# Dell XPS 15 L521X BIOS Password Reset

Tags: bios, passwords, dell-xps

I need to reset my BIOS password on my Dell XPS 15z as I can't get it to boot. I have tried removing CMOS battery and battery and seeing if that will do it but no luck. Any ideas maybe there a jumper on the laptop somewere

Answer (score 0):

Dell technical support should be able to provide you a master password to unlock the system if prompted by a BIOS password lock out. In order to generate, we would need to verify ownership of the system and collect order / account information through a private message.

Please feel free to reach out to us:

**Twitter:** @DellCaresPRO

**Dell Community Forums:** http://en.community.dell.com/members/dell_2d00_shawn-b/

**Email + US Chat and Phone:** http://www.dell.com/support/contents/us/en/19/category/Contact-Information/Technical-Support

Thanks,